# How to send a message with tuples in Akka.Remote with F#?

Tags: f#, akka, akka.net, f#-interactive

I am trying to send a message using remote in F# but I keep getting this problem where a message with a type is never sent. When I use the code given below :

Server.fsx

```
#r "nuget: Akka.FSharp" 
#r "nuget: Akka.TestKit"
#r "nuget: Akka.Remote"



open System
open Akka.FSharp
open Akka.Remote
open Akka.Configuration

let configuration = 
    ConfigurationFactory.ParseString(
        @"akka {
            actor {
                provider = ""Akka.Remote.RemoteActorRefProvider, Akka.Remote""
                debug : {
                    receive : on
                    autoreceive : on
                    lifecycle : on
                    event-stream : on
                    unhandled : on
                }
            }
            remote {
                helios.tcp {
                    port = 9002
                    hostname = 192.168.0.94
                }
            }
        }")

let serversystem = System.create "Server" configuration



let server (mailbox:Actor<_>) =
    let rec loop () = actor {
        let! message = mailbox.Receive()
        printfn "%s" message
    }
    loop ()

let serveRef = spawn serversystem "server" server
Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
```

Client.fsx

```
#r "nuget: Akka.FSharp" 
#r "nuget: Akka.TestKit"
#r "nuget: Akka.Remote"

open System
open Akka.FSharp
open Akka.Remote
open Akka.Configuration

let configuration = 
    ConfigurationFactory.ParseString(
        @"akka {
            actor {
                provider = ""Akka.Remote.RemoteActorRefProvider, Akka.Remote""
                
            }
            remote {
                helios.tcp {
                    port = 2552
                    hostname = localhost
                }
            }
        }")

let clientSystem = System.create "client" configuration

let serveRef = select ("akka.tcp://Server@192.168.0.94:9002/user/server") clientSystem
serveRef <! "Register"
Console.ReadLine()
```

The message is sent and I can see a "Register" printed in the server terminal. But the problem arises when I try to use a specific type of message being sent.
Output on server terminal:

```
[INFO][12/1/2020 2:37:43 AM][Thread 0001][remoting (akka://Server)] Starting remoting
[INFO][12/1/2020 2:37:43 AM][Thread 0001][remoting (akka://Server)] Remoting started; listening on addresses : [akka.tcp://Server@192.168.0.94:9002]
[INFO][12/1/2020 2:37:43 AM][Thread 0001][remoting (akka://Server)] Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://Server@192.168.0.94:9002]
Register
```

Now the code is

Server.fsx

```
#r "nuget: Akka.FSharp" 
#r "nuget: Akka.TestKit"
#r "nuget: Akka.Remote"
#load "Message.fsx"

open Message
open System
open Akka.FSharp
open Akka.Remote
open Akka.Configuration

let configuration = 
    ConfigurationFactory.ParseString(
        @"akka {
            actor {
                provider = ""Akka.Remote.RemoteActorRefProvider, Akka.Remote""
                debug : {
                    receive : on
                    autoreceive : on
                    lifecycle : on
                    event-stream : on
                    unhandled : on
                }
            }
            remote {
                helios.tcp {
                    port = 9002
                    hostname = 192.168.0.94
                }
            }
        }")

let serversystem = System.create "Server" configuration



let server (mailbox:Actor<_>) =
    let rec loop () = actor {
        let! message = mailbox.Receive()
        match message with
        | Message(num) -> printfn "Got a number %d" num
    }
    loop ()

let serveRef = spawn serversystem "server" server
Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
```

Client.fsx

```
#r "nuget: Akka.FSharp" 
#r "nuget: Akka.TestKit"
#r "nuget: Akka.Remote"
#load "Message.fsx"

open Message
open System
open Akka.FSharp
open Akka.Remote
open Akka.Configuration

let configuration = 
    ConfigurationFactory.ParseString(
        @"akka {
            actor {
                provider = ""Akka.Remote.RemoteActorRefProvider, Akka.Remote""
                
            }
            remote {
                helios.tcp {
                    port = 2552
                    hostname = localhost
                }
            }
        }")

let clientSystem = System.create "client" configuration

let serveRef = select ("akka.tcp://Server@192.168.0.94:9002/user/server") clientSystem
serveRef <! Message(10)
Console.ReadLine()
```

Message.fsx

```
type Message = 
              | Message of int
```

In this case the message never gets printed. Do we need to serialze the message before sending? If yes, then how to do it?
Else, what am I doing wrong?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Akka by default uses Newtonsoft.Json which [cannot](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/issues/999) [roundtrip](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/issues/1595) discriminated unions. You can switch to a different serializer (such as Akka.Serialization.Hyperion) or use e.g. [Akkling](https://github.com/Horusiath/Akkling), an F# optimised Akka.FSharp fork.
Using Akkling your system might look like:

Message.fsx

```
#r "nuget: Akkling" 
#r "nuget: Akka.Remote"
#r "nuget: Newtonsoft.Json"

type Message = Message of int
```

Server.fsx

```
#load "Message.fsx"

open Message
open System
open Akkling

let configuration = 
    Configuration.parse
        @"akka {
            actor {
                provider = ""Akka.Remote.RemoteActorRefProvider, Akka.Remote""
                debug : {
                    receive : on
                    autoreceive : on
                    lifecycle : on
                    event-stream : on
                    unhandled : on
                }
            }
            remote {
                helios.tcp {
                    port = 9002
                    hostname = localhost
                }
            }
        }"

let serversystem = System.create "Server" configuration

let rec server = function
| Message(num) ->
    printfn "Got a number %d" num
    become server

let serveRef = spawn serversystem "server" <| props(actorOf server)
Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
```

Client.fsx

```
#load "Message.fsx"

open Message
open System
open Akkling

let configuration =
    Configuration.parse
        @"akka {
            actor {
                provider = ""Akka.Remote.RemoteActorRefProvider, Akka.Remote""
            }
            remote {
                helios.tcp {
                    port = 2552
                    hostname = localhost
                }
            }
        }"

let clientSystem = System.create "client" configuration

let serveRef = select clientSystem "akka.tcp://Server@localhost:9002/user/server"
serveRef <! Message(10)
Console.ReadLine()
```